# How to implement OAuth2 authorization with the server in react native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, react-redux

I want to implement OAuth2 authorization in react native.I implemented code the following way.

```
      const HOST_ADRESS = "192.168.173.1"; //change with your own host
        const client_id   = "app";
        const username = "balan@gmail.com";
        const password = "12345";
        fetch('https://'+HOST_ADRESS+"/oauth/token", {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          },
          body: "client_id=app&client_secret=app1234&grant_type=pass&username="+username+"&password="+password
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log("******* RESPONSE *********  "+ JSON.stringify(responseJson));
            })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
          console.log("--------------responseText"+responseText);
         console.log("******* RESPONSE *********  "+ JSON.stringify(responseJson));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const data = {error: "A error happened"};
    //redux error.
    //dispatch(actionsCreators.errorLogin(data));
      console.log("+++++++++++++++++++error"+error);
    console.warn(error);
  });
```

But it always get an error like

**{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}**

Comment: Well... to bad OAuth2 spec doesn't really provide all of the implementation details. You have to look at you backend implementation what it really expect as headers etc. Grant types https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3 for example. The "pass" grant types seems suspicious to me, "client_credentials" are more commonly used to imply the "Resource Owner Password Credentials" flow.

Comment: Yes, more info on the backend is definitely needed